# Does group by on entire dataframe followed by filter column take more memory compared to selecting the columns first?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to understand the working of the below code snippets:

1. `titanic.groupby("Sex")["Age"].mean()`

This considers a group by sex for all columns, then selects Age column, then performs the aggregate.

2. `titanic[["Sex", "Age"]].groupby("Sex").mean()`

This fetches the sex, age columns. Then does a group by on sex. Then calculates the aggregate.

Is the 2nd option using lesser memory?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to use more memory, based on this test using [tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html):

```py
import tracemalloc
import pandas as pd

titanic = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
tracemalloc.start()
# titanic.groupby("Sex")["Age"].mean()
titanic[["Sex", "Age"]].groupby("Sex").mean()

print("Current: %d, Peak %d" % tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
```

`titanic.groupby("Sex")["Age"].mean()` gave `Current: 59549, Peak 69110`

`titanic[["Sex", "Age"]].groupby("Sex").mean()` gave `Current: 89642, Peak 125526`

This is however just a small data set of shape (891, 12).